# The Flow Registry with ID XXX reports that no Flow exists with Bucket XXX, Flow XXX

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I have PG A containing PG B, both versioned,and they are stored in Registry-A.After they were transfered from Registry-A to Registry-B,PG A was exported from Registry-B with error.

[image]

WHY??ANY HELP IS ARRRECIATE!

Comment: If PG A containing PG B transfer them from A-register to B-register,the PG B must not be Upload A-register.This is a BUG,can not fixed in the version